# split 1 line into 2 line using visual basic

Tags: vb.net, string

Example:

```
MY NAME IS STACKOVERFLOW
```

Results in:

```
MY(new line)
NAME(new line)
IS(new line)
STACKOVERFLOW(new line)
```

or

Example:

```
MY-NAME-IS-STACKOVERFLOW
```

Results in:

```
MY(new line)
NAME(new line)
IS(new line)
STACKOVERFLOW(new line)
```

I want to split the line into multiple lines using either a space or dash or whatever it is.

Comment: VB6 or VB.NET?  Also, do you want to split on spaces and dashes only?

Comment: You can also look at the String.Split() method if you are using .NET

Comment: im using VB6...nope it can be (/) or(")...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB6:

```
if InStr(originalstring, "-") <> 0 Then
    newstring = Replace$(originalstring, "-", vbCrLf)
else
    newstring = Replace$(originalstring, " ", vbCrLf)
```

If you are using VB.NET, then you can use the [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method.

Comment: thanks very much for the answer...i'm a beginner...is this code can be use for list box...because i wanna use 2 list box...the first list box for the original and the second as the result...